# The best approach to scaling bi-directional live connections into the hundred of thousands?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am wondering building an app, that allows live polling with many clients (think HQ trivia).
What is the best technology/approach to achieve this with high speed and low costs?

I worked with socket.io before, but I don't think it will be sufficient for the huge number of clients I am trying to connect.

My server runs on node.js

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely broad question, and can really only be addresses as such with very broad advice and recommendations.

Basically it's going to boil down to:

- using node's built-in [clustering](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/cluster.html) to make use of all the CPUs on each server,
- possibly also using some sort of load-balancing across multiple servers.

Socket.io really has nothing to do per-se with the number of connections. You might be able to reduce CPU cycles or memory usage by writing your own websocket library based on the native http/https modules, but probably at the sacrifice of stability, security and/or features. And no matter what you use, with enough traffic eventually you'll hit a bottleneck somewhere. It could be network bandwidth, CPU usage, memory, etc.

When you hit a bottleneck you just need to have a plan for increasing it. You can do that by upgrading your server to have more CPUs, memory or bandwidth, or you can have a load balancing setup and scale your number of servers.